# How can I install multiple ssh public keys from environment variable?

Tags: ansible, environment-variables, ssh-keys

I'm writing a little playbook I want to share with some people.
This playbook needs one or more ssh public keys to install on ansible nodes.

To make it easier to customize, I thought setting SSH public keys in an environment variable would be the best solution, but I can study any better proposal.

So, users just have to set this:

```
export ANSIBLE_SSH_PUBKEY=${HOME}/.ssh/my_ssh_key.pub
```

And in the playbook, this is handled like this:

```yaml
- name: Install ssh public key
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: ansible
    state: present
    key: '{{ item }}'
  with_file: '{{ lookup("env", "ANSIBLE_SSH_PUBKEY") }}'
```

Currently, I only manage one ssh public key installation.
So, my question is: how can I do to handle any number of public keys?

Comment: See @β.εηοιτ.βε for a direct answer to your question. Meanwhile, putting your task inside a correctly crafted role, defining a default variable in the role holding your list of keys so that it can be overridden very easily by your users in their inventory, inside their own playbook, directly on the command line... might a better way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't want to install default ssh public key because it is a major security risk if the user forget to customize these variables.

Comment: You can perfectly set a default variable as an empty list so that the role does not install anything by default.

Comment: So I can't understand the advantage of this solution. Can you elaborate or give a small explanatory link?

Comment: A role is reusable and adaptable by the user who you share it with. The role can have a default list of keys which is empty. Your user overrides the default list of keys in his inventory / playbook / command line to deploy whichever he needs. That's the basic way default role variables function (give a default value which the user can override at will).

Comment: Just a 2mn search so might not be the best/most advanced/best practice.... but [this role](https://github.com/julb/ansible-custom-ca) installs custom root CAs on a system from a list which is [empty by default](https://github.com/julb/ansible-custom-ca/blob/main/defaults/main.yml). So for example the [following task](https://github.com/julb/ansible-custom-ca/blob/f1e5287aa53ce068f8bcf8aa6905f16b63d7dab7/tasks/main.yml#L30) will loop on nothing if you don't populate the list yourself while using the role, as explained in the repository README

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either allow them to import all their public key, with a [`with_fileglob`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html) loop instead:

```sh
export ANSIBLE_SSH_FOLDER=~/.ssh
```

```yaml
- name: Install ssh public key
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: ansible
    state: present
    key: '{{ item }}'
  with_fileglob: '{{ lookup("env", "ANSIBLE_SSH_FOLDER") }}/*'
```

Or allow them for a colon separated value, then split the environment variable on that separator:

```sh
export ANSIBLE_SSH_PUBKEY=~/.ssh/my_ssh_key.pub:~/.ssh/my_other_ssh_key.pub
```

```yaml
- name: Install ssh public key
  ansible.posix.authorized_key:
    user: ansible
    state: present
    key: '{{ item }}'
  with_file: '{{ (lookup("env", "ANSIBLE_SSH_PUBKEY")).split(":") }}'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. I just had to change split(':') into split(":").
I didn't try the fileglob because I don't want to install all my public keys.